# Swift: Is there a faster, more responsive way to implement different corner radii for a UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit, calayer

Currently, I implement multiple corner radii on my `bubbleView` which is a `UIView` by doing something along the lines of:

```swift
// First create the bubble view
bubbleView = UIView()
bubbleView.layer.cornerRadius = 4 // set the corner radius of the "smaller" corner style
bubbleView.layer.cornerCurve = .continuous
bubbleView.clipsToBounds = true
bubbleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBlue

// ...

// Update the "mask" of the bubble view to give another type of rounded corners
let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:bubbleView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 17.0, height: 0.0))
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
bubbleView.layer.mask = maskLayer // updates the mask
```

My issue is I am setting the mask, `self.bubbleView.layer.mask = maskLayer`, of the `bubbleView` in the `func layoutSubviews()` function, which causes a noticable delay, for example, when the device rotates from portrait to landscape mode.

**Is there a faster, more efficient way to implement different corner radii for a `UIView` that responds faster than simply updating the mask in `layoutSubviews()` ?**

Comment: It is foolish to round the layer corners _and_ add a rounded rect mask.

Comment: Interesting, @matt why would this be? I use the `bubbleView.layer` as a mask, and to the best of my knowledge, I cannot set multiple masks for a CALayer (and I need to mask a layer with different corner radii)?  Would you have any other suggestions for a more viable approach? Thanks

Comment: Oh yes, you can shape a bezier path mask any way you like.

Comment: Also remember `layoutSubviews` is called unpredictably. Check the bounds and do no work if they don’t change, just call super.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a subview with the larger radius corners...

- custom view
- clear background
- all 4 corners set to Radius of 4
- subView with desired background color
- set Radius of 17 on desired corners of subView

Here's some sample code:

```
class MyCustomView: UIView {

    // self's background will be .clear
    //  so we use a custom property to set the
    //  background of the subView
    public var viewColor: UIColor = .clear {
        didSet {
            subView.backgroundColor = viewColor
        }
    }
    
    // corners to use larger radius
    public var corners: CACornerMask = [] {
        didSet {
            subView.layer.maskedCorners = corners
        }
    }
    
    public var smallRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = smallRadius
        }
    }

    public var bigRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            subView.layer.cornerRadius = bigRadius
        }
    }
    
    private let subView = UIView()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        addSubview(subView)
        subView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            subView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            subView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            subView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            subView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
        ])

        // round all 4 corners of self's layer with the small radius
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.cornerRadius = smallRadius
        layer.cornerCurve = .continuous

        // subview only specified corners with bigger radius
        subView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        subView.layer.cornerRadius = bigRadius
        subView.layer.cornerCurve = .continuous
        subView.layer.maskedCorners = corners

    }
    
}
```

and a test view controller to demo it:

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let v = MyCustomView()

        v.viewColor = .systemBlue
        v.smallRadius = 4
        v.bigRadius = 17
        
        // set top-left, top-right, bottom-left to use larger radius
        v.corners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner]
        
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(v)
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 60.0),
            v.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -60.0),
            v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120.0),
            v.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
}
```